# how can I parse a date from excel in 09-Jan-2019 format and convert it into yyyy-mm-dd format using python

Tags: python, excel, date

I have a date with some string in excel cell like, 'As of 09-Jan-2019' 
I need to parse this date and convert it into yyyy/mm/day format

'to_search = "%d-%b-%y"'

```
'for i in range(sheet.ncols):'
'for j in range(sheet.nrows):'
'if sheet.cell_value(i,j) == re.search(to_search, txt)'
'print sheet.cell_value(i,j)'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: use pandas.to_datetime : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

Comment: Date formats are not part of regex. You need to find the date-like thing using regex, then try to parse this part only using date parser with this format of yours - if it parses, then it's successfully found. After that you replaces the value with re-formatted one. And voila!

Answer (score 0):

Using python you can do it with dateutil lib (`pip install python-dateutil`) and some initial string slicing:

```
import dateutil.parser
s =  'As of 09-Jan-2019' 
t = dateutil.parser.parse(s[5:])
t.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
```

returns `2019/01/09`

Comment: works...thanks... but I need to parse it from excel

Answer (score 0):

from datetime import datetime

date = "09-Jan-2019"

new_date_format=datetime.strptime(date, "%d-%b-%Y").date()

print(new_date_format)

Comment: yes...this works... thank you.... But I need to parse it from excel cell but I don't know the loc... I need to find it wherever it is

Comment: You'll have to use the xlrd library with which you can specify the cells or rows the date is in and for each row get the string, strip the date end rewrite that cell.

Answer (score 0):

import xlrd

loc = ("path of file")

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)

sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

sheet.cell_value(0, 0)

Comment: Use variables in a nested for loop with: "sheet.cell_value(i,j)" then you can test as many cells as possible